# What is wrong with the result of the if else statement

Tags: python

I have a simple if else statement, that gives me the wrong result.

```
a=36
MITTEN = 42
if a <= MITTEN:
  print("A", end=" ")
  print("B", end=" ")
else:
  print("C", end=" ")
  print("D")
```

This gives me the result **A B**

but the correct answer should be **A B D**

Comment: No, it is not. `"D"` belongs to the else part. If it doesn't, unindent it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are expecting to get in both cases.

If you are expecting `A B D` if and only if `a <= MITTEN` then you should put `print("D")` to the if clause:

```
a=36
MITTEN = 42
if a <= MITTEN:
  print("A", end=" ")
  print("B", end=" ")
  print("D")
else:
  print("C", end=" ")
```

On the other hand, if you are expecting to `print("D")` independently of the outcome of `a <= MITTEN` then you should remove the indent in the last line:

```
a=36
MITTEN = 42
if a <= MITTEN:
  print("A", end=" ")
  print("B", end=" ")
else:
  print("C", end=" ")
print("D")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should Always keep in mind that :
"Whitespace is significant in Python source code."
so don't just read source code from top to down but also care about Indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Unindent the `print ("D")` line. In your code that line will execute only if the condition 
`a <= MITTEN:` is `False`.

```
a=36
MITTEN = 42
if a <= MITTEN:
    print("A", end=" ")
    print("B", end=" ")
else:
    print("C", end=" ")
print("D")
```

Note that now if that condition is `False` the output would be `C D` and if `True` it would be  `A B D`.

And use four spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Unindent the last line

```
a=36
MITTEN = 42
if a <= MITTEN:
  print("A", end=" ")
  print("B", end=" ")
else:
  print("C", end=" ")
print("D")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is homework for something, if you're pasting only the answer in and not the code, then either the program determining whether your answer is correct is sensitive to whether there is a trailing space added by the `end` parameter to the print function, or as I've just seen the other answers come in (who seem more familiar with the course you're doing!), it may be down to indentation; if that 'D' is supposed to be printed last, it can't be in the first conditional.